# Не закрывается модальное окно magnific-popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, вёрстка

Использую плагин [magnific-popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) для модальных окон и столкнулся с такой проблемой: как только в кнопку close вставить какое нибудь инородное изображение или svg то она тут же перестает функционировать, то есть по кнопе теперь модалка не закрывается. Все корректно работает если вставить это изображение в качестве фона для кнопки, но хочу понять почему это происходит именно с объектом внутри кнопки и как это пофиксить?

С чем это связано, сталкивался еще кто?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.popup-with-form').magnificPopup({
  type: 'inline',
  preloader: false,
  focus: '#name',

  // When elemened is focused, some mobile browsers in some cases zoom in
  // It looks not nice, so we disable it:
  callbacks: {
   beforeOpen: function() {
    if($(window).width() < 700) {
     this.st.focus = false;
    } else {
     this.st.focus = '#name';
    }
   }
  }
 });
});
```

```css
.white-popup-block {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.close img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Magnific Popup core CSS file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/magnific-popup.min.css">

<!-- jQuery 1.7.2+ or Zepto.js 1.0+ -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Magnific Popup core JS file -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>



<!-- link that opens popup -->
<a class="popup-with-form" href="#test-form">Open form</a>

<!-- form itself -->
<form id="test-form" class="white-popup-block mfp-hide">
 <h1>Form</h1>
 <fieldset style="border:0;">
  <p>Lightbox has an option to automatically focus on the first input. It's strongly recommended to use <code>inline</code> popup type for lightboxes with form instead of <code>ajax</code> (to keep entered data if the user accidentally refreshed the page).</p>
  <ol>
   <li>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" required="">
   </li>
   <li>
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="example@domain.com" required="">
   </li>
   <li>
    <label for="phone">Phone</label>
    <input id="phone" name="phone" type="tel" placeholder="Eg. +447500000000" required="">
   </li>
   <li>
    <label for="textarea">Textarea</label><br>
    <textarea id="textarea">Try to resize me to see how popup CSS-based resizing works.</textarea>
   </li>
  </ol>
 </fieldset>
  <button title="Close (Esc)" type="button" class="mfp-close close"><img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/Q/3/G/C/7/W/close-md.png" alt=""></button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно, проблема заключается в том, что закрытие происходит по клику на элементе с определёнными служебными классами. В данном случае это .mfp-close.close, которые есть у button, но которых нет у img (или любого другого элемента, добавленного внутрь).

Более того, если Вы хотите использовать в качестве закрывающего элемента картинку, у Вас вообще нет нужды оставлять в разметке button - кнопку можно смело удалять. Ну и не очень понятно, к чему это абсолютное позиционирование - достаточно зафлоатить картинку вправо и задать 10-ти пиксельные маргины (плюс курсор: поинтер):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.popup-with-form').magnificPopup({
  type: 'inline',
  preloader: false,
  focus: '#name',

  // When elemened is focused, some mobile browsers in some cases zoom in
  // It looks not nice, so we disable it:
  callbacks: {
   beforeOpen: function() {
    if($(window).width() < 700) {
     this.st.focus = false;
    } else {
     this.st.focus = '#name';
    }
   }
  }
 });
});
```

```css
.white-popup-block {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

img.close {
  float: right;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!-- Magnific Popup core CSS file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/magnific-popup.min.css">

<!-- jQuery 1.7.2+ or Zepto.js 1.0+ -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Magnific Popup core JS file -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>



<!-- link that opens popup -->
<a class="popup-with-form" href="#test-form">Open form</a>

<!-- form itself -->
<form id="test-form" class="white-popup-block mfp-hide">
 <h1>Form</h1>
 <fieldset style="border:0;">
  <p>Lightbox has an option to automatically focus on the first input. It's strongly recommended to use <code>inline</code> popup type for lightboxes with form instead of <code>ajax</code> (to keep entered data if the user accidentally refreshed the page).</p>
  <ol>
   <li>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" required="">
   </li>
   <li>
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="example@domain.com" required="">
   </li>
   <li>
    <label for="phone">Phone</label>
    <input id="phone" name="phone" type="tel" placeholder="Eg. +447500000000" required="">
   </li>
   <li>
    <label for="textarea">Textarea</label><br>
    <textarea id="textarea">Try to resize me to see how popup CSS-based resizing works.</textarea>
   </li>
  </ol>
 </fieldset>
  <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/Q/3/G/C/7/W/close-md.png" alt="" class="mfp-close close">
</form>
```